# Taxonomy images in Drupal, Is there a way to manually add a thumbnail image?

Tags: php, drupal

We have the taxonomy image module installed, uploaded some taxonomy images a made a happy dance. Thumbnails where needed so we used the taxonomy_image_display() which does a fairly good job (although constrained to 150 x 150px). What we need now is a way to manually add a taxonomy image thumbnail for those special cases where the designer feels he wants to frame the thumbnail himself. Can this be done? So far the taxonomy image module only allows you to set one taxonomy image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like taxonomy image integrates with imagecache, (http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/taxonomy_image_display/6), so setting up a preset might get you there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be checking it out